# How can i use a third party oauth service with Azure ACS?

Tags: azure, acs

I've been browsing a lot on both StackOverflow and a bunch of different Microsoft associated sites and looking at examples etc but I think I'm missing a few key point to the problem in hand.

Scenario: 
I'm developing a site that uses Yammer (Facebook style page for those of you who don't know) as a Identity Provider together with ACS to provide the security for my site.

Now Iv'e been trying to follow along with a bunch of exercises from MS on how to build those custom providers (Identity Developer Training Kit) but to the question, do I actually have to build them? Isn't there a way to configure ACS to handle my tokens from Yammer (Powershell commands?)? Or do I have to create a STS provider site and "bridge" Yammer and actually provide ACS with my "own" tokens.

So this question is a little bit on an extension on [another one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318173/oauth-2-0-identity-providers-in-windows-azure-appfabric-access-control-service)

Answer (score 1):

The ACS does not support OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

As I understand it; OAuth it for *Authorization*, the ACS is for *Authentication*.

It does support WS-Federation and OpenID (although only through the API) identity providers, you just need to add the configuration in the ACS.

So if Yammer has an OpenID or or WS-Federation, you're in business.

If not, it's fairly straight forward to build your own identity provider (thinktecture have one you can use as a starting point: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2009/05/thinktecture-security-token-service-starter-kit---or-look-ma-even-i-can-have-a-sts.html) which you could use to 'bridge the gap' between some other authentication method and the ACS. You would just need to register it as a WS-Federation identity provider in the ACS using it's FederationMetadata.xml file. Your identity provider would then need to determine whether the user is authentic or not.

Comment: Yebb, i was in thoose terms as well.... then ill continue on that path! Thnx for the input!